# iOS SDK, Objective-C, uitable only showing one cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a textfield that the user inputs, then I save it with NSKeyedArchiver and pull it out to view on the table but every time I enter something in the textfield and save it, it replaces the first item in the cell, I want it to add it to the table.

in NewEntry.m where I save the data with

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {




int i = selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex;

app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setInteger:i  forKey:@"category"];





if (i == 0) {

   // [userDefaults setObject:titlefield.text forKey: @"titlehomework"];
// [userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"detailshomework"];

    NSMutableArray *contactArray;

    contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [contactArray addObject:titlefield.text];
    [contactArray addObject:detailstextfield.text];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: 
     contactArray toFile:datafilePath];


}

else if(selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [userDefaults setObject:titlefield.text forKey:@"titletextprojects"];
[userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"detailsprojects"];

}
else if (selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
    [userDefaults setObject:titlefield.text forKey:@"titletextappointments"];
    [userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"detailsappointments"];
}
else if (selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){
    [userDefaults setObject:titlefield.text forKey:@"titletextevents"];
    [userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"detailsevents"];

}

else if (selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4){
    [userDefaults setObject:titlefield.text forKey:@"titletexttodolist"];
    [userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"detailstodolist"];
}

/*[userDefaults synchronize];
titlefield.text =@" ";
detailstextfield.text =@" ";
NSLog(@"selected segment %i", i);*/

/* UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Task saved!" message:@"You're all done." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex];
[alert show];*/

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ValuesChanged"
                                                    object:self];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

NewEntry ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if (__managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    __managedObjectContext = [(StaticTableAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext_: %@",  __managedObjectContext);
}




NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the data file
datafilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir 
                                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

// Check if the file already exists
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: datafilePath])
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;

    dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver 
                 unarchiveObjectWithFile: datafilePath];

    //titlefield.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
  //  detailstextfield.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:1];

}





}
```

new entry ViewDidUnload:

```
 - (void)viewDidUnload
{


[self setTitleTextfield:nil];
[self setCategory:nil];
[self setDetailstextfield:nil];
[self setTitlefield:nil];
[self setTitlefield:nil];
[self setSelectedSegment:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

}
```

And in the table controller I call it here:
tableview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//  [self fetchRecords];  
if(tablesubtitles == nil && tabledata == nil){
tablesubtitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}    

NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the data file
datafilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir 
                                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];


// Check if the file already exists
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: datafilePath])
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;

    dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver 
                 unarchiveObjectWithFile: datafilePath];


    titlestring = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0 ];
    detailsstring = [dataArray objectAtIndex:1];



    [tabledata addObject:titlestring];
    [tablesubtitles addObject:detailsstring];
    }






}
```

and:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];


if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"homework"];

 }



NSString *cellValue = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *subtitle = [tablesubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




cell.textLabel.text= cellValue;

cell.detailTextLabel.text= subtitle;

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor    =   [ UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];       



    //[tabledata addObjectser.title];
    //[tabledata addObject:user.detai/s];   

//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



// Configure the cell.

//-----------------------------------------START----------------------------Set image of cell----
cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];

cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

//--------------------------------------------END---------------------------end set image of cell--  

return cell;


}
```

**********************UPDATE***********************
So in saveButton it should be:

```
  NSMutableArray *contactArray;
   contactArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver 
       unarchiveObjectWithFile: datafilePath];

   // contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [contactArray addObject:titlefield.text];
    [contactArray addObject:detailstextfield.text];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: 
     contactArray toFile:datafilePath];

    // NSDictionary *stuff;
```

?

Comment: There is a huge amount of unrelated and commented out code in this question. You should edit it down to the parts you are concerned about, people will be more willing to read it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new mutable array, putting one item in it, and then archiving that array to your file. This is going to replace whatever was there before.

To add a new item you need to unarchive the array first, add to that array, and then archive your new array.

There seems to be some core data code in here as well, there is little merit in doing your own archiving if you are going to use core data.

Comment: Oh, I kind of understand. So do you mean in the saveButton method? I understand what you mean but not sure where

Comment: Yes, that's the only place I can see where you use the archiver. You need to unarchive like you do in the viewDidLoad method first, and add to that array. You may need to make a mutable array with the unarchiver array, I think the unarchiver returns an immutable NSArray.

Comment: i ran it and changed the objectAtIndex 2 and 3 but get the error that the array doesn't have a third index, not that big